# Mysql query replace first empty string

Tags: mysql

I have many fields that contains extra space in start, like:

```
" RTX 3060"
-^
```

I want to remove first extra space from all fields of this table.

What I tried:

```
UPDATE table set field = concat( '', substring(field , 1)) where left(field ,1)=' ';
```

*Return 0 result!*

Comment: I think you need 2 on substring insted of one. But still there are couples I can think of

`UPDATE table set field = concat( '', substring(field , 2)) where field LIKE " %"`
or
`UPDATE table set field = substring(field , 2) where field LIKE " %"`

Comment: @RajeshPaudel Backticks format code, asterisks are simply for bold.

Comment: If you have MySQL 8.0 or better, consider [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

Comment: @tadman thanks I have a habit of putting three backticks maybe that's why it wasn't working. I realised i could put one instead of three. Thank You

Comment: @RajeshPaudel One for inline, three for block form, which I believe only works in answers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this statement, it will remove only the first space char of field is it's a space:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET column = SUBSTRING(column,2)
WHERE SUBSTRING(column, 1, 1) = ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the LTRIM function. The syntax looks something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = LTRIM(column);
```

Comment: LTRIM remove ALL first chars, the question is about removing the **first** extra space, not all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).